# How to publish multiple artifacts with different group using gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have 2 artifacts I want to push.
first one is a tar ball called myTarBall-1.1.tar.gz
second one is a jar file myJarFile-1.1.jar

I want to push myTarBall-1.1.tar.gz into nexus to the following location com.sample.location.abc.
I then want to push myJarFile-1.1.jar into nexus to the following location com.sample.location.xyz.

How would I go about doing that?

Thus far, I am only successful in pushing the myTarBall-1.1.tar.gz to com.sample.location.abc, but I can't figure out how to push myJarFile-1.1.jar to com.sample.location.xyz...

Any help would be appreciated...

Below is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins 
{
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = "com.sample.location.abc"
version = "1.1"
def artifact_tar = 'myTarBall'
def artifact_jar = 'myJarFile'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "${project.group}"
            artifactId = "${artifact_tar}"
            version = "${version}"
            artifact source: "${artifact_tar}-${version}.tar.gz", extension: "tar.gz"

            ??? How to also push myJarFile-1.1.jar to com.sample.location.xyz in here???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `maven(MavenPublication)` for the second artifact?

Comment: @user16358266 Goodness gracious... Dude, you are the man!!! Thanks for that idea... I tried so many things and did not even think of adding another publication... I was under the assumption that only 1 publication is allowed... Thank you so much, it worked..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to push artifacts to different groups, I simply needed to add a new publication, which was suggested by @user16358266

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenOne(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "${project.group}"
            artifactId = "${artifact_tar}"
            version = "${version}"
            artifact source: "${artifact_tar}-${version}.tar.gz", extension: "tar.gz" 
        }
    mavenTwo(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "${**new.group.id**}"
            artifactId = "${artifact_jar}"
            version = "${version}"
            artifact source: "${artifact_jar}-${version}.jar", extension: "jar" 
        }
    }
}
```